# Python 'NoneType' Object Has No Attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am testing out Python a little and have been following some lessons, but i am quite stuck at this point:

```
urls = []
for h3_tag in soup.find_all("h3"):
    a_tag = h3_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])
print(urls)
```

This is supposed to get the "a" inside a set of h3. And it does, but when i then add the .attrs['href'] or the .text in order to get the URL Anchor or the URL itself i keep getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

I cant seem to work it out...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do **all** the `h3` tags have anchors?

Comment: not all of them, no

Comment: `find` returns `None` if it didn't find the element.

Comment: Okay, so you need to test `if a_tag is not None` before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it doesn't find an `a` tag, then you can't get the `href` attribute, if it even has one. I'd incorporate a try/except here then, or as stated in the comment, check if it's `None`

```
urls = []
for h3_tag in soup.find_all("h3"):
    try:
        a_tag = h3_tag.find('a')
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])
    except:
        continue
print(urls)
```

Comment: Ok, so that seems to work... i gues i am quite a noob haha. Thanks!

Comment: hey, we all start as noobs! No worries! Keep learning, practicing, and asking questions!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by **`chitown88`** you should ensure that **`h3_tag.find('a')`** does not return **`None`**.

#### However, you should avoid doing it with unrestricted `try` and `except` statements. It can make troubleshooting difficult in the future. An alternative to my version would be to simply place a `KeyError` after the except clause. i.e. `except KeyError:`

See here for more details

- [Link 1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/)
- [Link 2](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html)

---

**Here is my preferred way to handle this**

```py
urls = []

for h3_tag in soup.find_all("h3"):
    # Get the a-tag or set a_tag to None if no a-tag is found
    a_tag = h3_tag.find('a')

    # Guarantee that we were able to find an a-tag
    if a_tag:        
        # Guarantee that the a_tag has an `href` attribute
        if a.get('href'):
            urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])

print(urls)
```

---

**I hope this helps!**

Comment: `should avoid doing it with unrestricted try and **except** statements`. Can you expand on that? Not trying to argue...just trying to learn and always improve. Why is your solution the correct way?

Comment: There exist two ways of handling potential exceptions:

One is called **EAFP** - Easier to Ask for Forgiveness Than Ask For Permission.

The other is called **LBYL** - Look Before You Leap.

I am not debating whether or not EAFP is better or worse than LBYL (although I prefer LBYL). What is without debate is that **try-except** statements are for catching a particular error. Having nothing following your except statement is bad practice.

If you had put `except KeyError():` .. that would have made more sense and been valid.

Ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/

Comment: For additional reading see here - https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html

**Comments from docs regarding an empty `except` clause**

`The last except clause may omit the exception name(s), to serve as a wildcard. Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way! It can also be used to print an error message and then re-raise the exception (allowing a caller to handle the exception as well):`

Comment: I hope that helps! Sorry if I came across abrasive. That was not my intention.

I simply have had to debug a lot of code that contains empty except clauses and it is truly horrible when troubleshooting. I always recommend taking the extra second to be a bit more verbose. It'll save the next person a lot of headaches.

I've updated my answer to say an `alternative way`. Sorry about that!

Comment: Oh no no! I didn't take it as abrasive. I genuinely wanted to understand. Ya that makes sense then though. Thanks for replying!